# Backbone on('add') not being called

Tags: backbone.js

I defined the **add** handler on my collection:

```
var BookmarksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('add', function(obj) {
            console.log(obj.get('title') + ' added');
        });
    },
    url: '/bookmarks',
    model: Bookmark   
});
```

And it's being called from one of my views:

```
var AddView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#entry'),
    events: {
        'click #submit': 'submitHandler'
    },
    submitHandler: function(event) {
        if($('input').val()) {
            var newBookmark = new Bookmark;
            newBookmark.set({url: $('input').val()});
            console.log('Save!');
            newBookmark.save({
                success: function(newBookmark) {    
                    console.log('Success!');                
                    myBookmarks.add(newBookmark);
                    myBookmarks.trigger('add', newBookmark);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

However the add handler on my collection is never triggered. In fact, not even the **success** function in the view seems to be called.

But the newBookmark gets saved anyway, so no errors happening.

What am I missing?

NodeJS respond with **201 (Created)**  when a new bookmark is posted.

Maybe backbone expects a **200 (OK)** to trigger success?

**EDIT:** I tried triggering the event from outside the success function and it works.
How can I tweak backbone to react to a **201 (Created)**?

Comment: You could try the `error` callback and just check the status for a 201 if you didn't want to go an mess with Backbone's code. I suspect it might even be inside of jQuery that the success/error are determined.

Comment: Just tried. Error is not being called neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that he first argument of `save` should be the data you are trying to save. The second is the options which can include the `success` and `error` callbacks.

```
newBookmark.save({dataiwanttosave: "hi"}, {
  success: function(newBookmark) {    
    console.log('Success!');                
    myBookmarks.add(newBookmark);
    myBookmarks.trigger('add', newBookmark);
  }
```

});